# expected concept name with optional arguments

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I know absolutely nothing about concepts but I was interested to learn a bit about them. So I am reading a book *template metaprogramming with c++ [Marius Bancila]*.

I was trying out an example :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <concepts>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
concept timer = requires(T t)
{
        {t.start()} -> std::same_as<void>;
        {t.stop()} -> std::convertible_to<long long>;
};

struct timerA
{
        void start(){}
        long long stop(){return 0;}
};

struct timerB
{
        void start(){}
        int stop(){return 0;}
};

struct timerC
{
        void start(){}
        void stop(){}
        long long getTick(){return 0;}
};

static_assert(timer<timerA>);
static_assert(timer<timerB>);
static_assert(!timer<timerC>);
```

compiled with clang++

```
main.cpp:9:16: error: expected concept name with optional arguments
        {t.stop()} -> std::convertible_to<long long>;
                      ^
main.cpp:39:1: error: static_assert failed due to requirement '!timer<timerC>'
static_assert(!timer<timerC>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

is there a typo in the source?

Comment: What version of Clang are you using? [None of the ones I tried had that problem](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Gve17eb4o). Is this maybe an old MacOS version or something?

Comment: `clang --version` says `13.0.0`. I am using Mac M1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the standard library implementation that you're using is too old, and the `<concepts>` header does not contain a definition of the `std::convertible_to` concept. You're probably using libc++ version 11 or 12, both of which provided a `<concepts>` header that contained `std::same_as` but not `std::convertible_to`. libc++ version 13 onwards has a definition for `std::convertible_to`.

The definition of `convertible_to` is pretty simple, so you can define your own for experimentation purposes, but it would be better to upgrade your standard library implementation if possible. Here's a sample implementation from cppreference:

```
template <class From, class To>
concept convertible_to =
  std::is_convertible_v<From, To> &&
  requires {
    static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>());
  };
```